# Инкремент глобальной переменой из таска

Tags: c#

Как правильно увеличивать глобальную переменную внутри таска ?

А то получается что использую одни и те же числа по несколько раз(

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        List<int> listChisel = new List<int>();
        int counter = 0;

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                listChisel.Add(i);
            }

            ZapuskPotokov(100);
        }


        private void ZapuskPotokov(int viborKolPotokov)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < viborKolPotokov; i++)
            {
                Task.Run(() => Algoritm());
            }
        }

        private void Algoritm()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(listChisel[counter]);
            counter++;
        }
    }
}
```

Ожидаю например: 195246837... - где все числа уникальны

Получаю: 000433221..

Comment: 1) поле должно быть отмечено как volatile, чтобы не кешировалось на поток 2) Увеличивать его значение надо этим [Interlocked.Increment Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked.increment?view=net-5.0), чтобы операция была атомарна. Простое counter ++ превращается в 2 операции, а там уже возможна race condition.

Comment: м тем не менее, раз у вас метод `Algoritm` выполняется параллельно, всё равно есть вероятность вывода одинаковых чисел. Я бы сам метод немного переписал `Debug.WriteLine(listChisel[Interlocked.Increment(ref counter)]);`

Comment: `Ожидаю например: 195246837` Результат будет более-менее упорядоченным, хотя это зависит от того, как `Debug.WriteLine` обрабатывает многопоточные вызовы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что переменная `counter` не потокобезопасна. 4 потока ее читают, потом 2 пишут, потом 3 читают, вразнобой. Чтобы исправить это, нужно сделать так, чтобы читать и писать в переменную мог одновременно только один поток. При чем между чтением и записью в одном потоке, другой поток не мог её ни читать, ни писать.

```
private object _locker = new object();

private void Algoritm()
{
    int value;
    lock (_locker)
    {
        value = listChisel[counter++];
    }
    Debug.WriteLine(value);
}
```

Или так, с учетом, что список ни кем не изменяется, пока работают потоки.

```
private object _locker = new object();

private void Algoritm()
{
    int index;
    lock (_locker)
    {
        index = counter++;
    }
    Debug.WriteLine(listChisel[index]);
}
```

Или даже так, с помощью атомарного инкремента

```
private void Algoritm()
{
    int index = Interlocked.Increment(ref counter) - 1;
    Debug.WriteLine(listChisel[index]);
}
```

В [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked.increment?view=netcore-3.1) `Interlocked.Increment` ошибка в переводе на русский.

> #### Возвращаемое значение
>
> `Int32`
> Увеличиваемое значение.

Тогда как в английском

> #### Returns
>
> `Int32`
> The incremented value.

Что в переводе означает "**увеличенное** значение", а не увеличиваемое.

Кстати, `Interlocked.Increment` очень быстрый, ну потому что это всего одна аппаратная инструкция, и на ассемблере выглядит она так:

```
lock add dword ptr [rcx], 1
```

Где регистр `rcx` содержит адрес `ref counter` в памяти.

Comment: Монитры обычно тяжеловесные, `Interlocked.Increment(ref counter)` думаю будет пошустрее. Да и смысл тасков тогда, если весь метод однопоточный получается.

Comment: и не забывайте про `volatile`. Я уж точно детали не помню, но вроде даже в вашем варианте его надо применять на counter

Comment: (если посчитаете инфу и моих комментов под вопросом полезной, смело добавляйте в ответ. Мне просто лень ответ самому оформлять :) )

Comment: всю конструкцию во втором варианте можно заменить на `Debug.WriteLine(listChisel[Interlocked.Increment(ref counter)]);` - это будет то же самое по логике, но побыстрее по скорости.

Comment: @tym32167 интерлокед не поможет, потому что помимо инкремента нужно еще и получить значение до инкремента. `volatile` при работе под локом разве нужен? Я не уверен, но спорить не буду, сам уже не помню.

Comment: ок ок, тогда просто вот так `Debug.WriteLine(listChisel[Interlocked.Increment(ref counter) - 1]);`

Comment: про volatile я сам не помню. Просто логически если рассуждать - то lock ограничивает выполнение одним потоком но вроде не препятсвует кешированию расшаренных между потоками полей. Но я могу быть и не прав тут

Comment: @tym32167 Вот хорошая ссылка, чтобы освежить это всё https://stackoverflow.com/a/154803/8324991

Comment: @tym32167 Там пишут, что `volatile` вообще нужен только для одного частного случая - когда есть два потока, один из которых читает, а второй пишет, тогда можно им обойтись без лока и т.д. А так то `lock` и `interlocked` делают всё что нужно, `volatile` не нужен.

Comment: @tym32167 пропустил момент, что интерлокед еще и значение возвращает, думал он `void`. Дополнил ответ.

Comment: @CrazyElf о, спасибо, тогда отмена операции, volatile можно вычеркнуть :)

Comment: @tym32167 почему волатиль для интерлокеда не походит: потому что интерлокед - это одна процессорная инструкция, которая на время своего выполнения лочит кешлайн процессора так, что другие ядра перезапрашивают на следующем такте этот кешлайн, так как не могут получить его на текущем, и так каждый такт, пока кешлайн не будет разлочен. Такой аппаратный лок. Тогда как волатиль вообще влияет на другое. Другими словами, волатиль несовместим с такой операцией, и он вообще про другое.

Comment: я ж не говорил, что volatile для interlocked - я имею ввиду volatile для кода, что у аатора. Volatile влияет на кеширование\оптимизации, не обязательно на уровне процессора, то есть я рассматривал volatile и interlocked как не связанные между собой вещи. По ссылке выше написано, что они таки связанные, хотя я не очень понял как именно.

Comment: @tym32167 я не пытался вас поправить, я пытался рассказать, как interlocked методы устроены. Но видимо кривовато получилось. :)